# Block access to subdirectories through primary domain

Tags: web-config

I have a windows shared hosting. I have three domains hosted here.

```
1. www.mysite.com <-------- Primary domain
2. www.friendsite.com <------- hosted in friendsite folder/sub-directory.
3. www.anothersite.com <------ hosted in anothersite folder/sub-directory.
```

Above three domains are working properly. But the problem is when I open `www.mysite.com/friendsite`, `www.friendsite.com` contents are visible or if I open `www.mysite.com/anothersite`, `www.anothersite.com` contents are visible as these are hosted in two sub-directories.

Is there any way to block the view of these particular sub-directories through the primary domain i.e. `www.mysite.com/friendsite` or `www.mysite.com/anothersite` ?

I don't want to block `www.friendsite.com` and `www.anothersite.com`. I just want to block `www.mysite.com/friendsite` and `www.mysite.com/anothersite`.

`.htaccess` will not work as it is a windows shared hosting, but `web.config` may work in this problem but I do not know how.

I think, I described my problem properly.

Please do not mark this question as **duplicate**.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not able to have a directory structure such as:

1. /websites/mysite
2. /websites/friendsite
3. /websites/othersite

The in IIS, create 3 different sites, each with its unique base directory, and set the bindings on the site itself to:
1. www.mysite.com:80
2. www.friendsite.com:80
3. www.othersite.com:80

??

Comment: Sorry... As `mysite` is primary domain, I cannot host it in sub-directory. only `friendsite` and `anothersite` can be hosted in sub-directories. And for your information, it is a shared hosting. I do not have full access to IIS.

Comment: What if you add a redirect IF the URL == mysite on each of your "other" sites that will redirect to you main site, when the URL contains "mysite.com"

Comment: Thanks, but where to put this `redirecting` code ? in mysite.com root or inside friendsite or anothersite folder ? Ok, I am explaining.... If anybody opens the website `www.friendsite.com` it will be viewed but if anybody opens `www.mysite.com/friendsite` the site content will not be viewed. I just want to do this.